# Vanguard UK lets you invest in the S&P 500 index fund. What about my taxes?

Tags: united-states, taxes, investing, united-kingdom, vanguard

Vanguard UK lets you invest in the S&P 500 index fund via an ISA (Independent Savings Fund). I understand that an ISA in the UK shields you from any tax on your profits from investments (up to a limit).  This fund is authorised in Ireland and regulated by the Central Bank of Ireland.

I'm confused. There is no mention of paying a US tax. As a UK citizen, would I have to pay a tax on my profits from investing in US companies? Do I have to sort this out independently with the IRS or do I sort that out with HMRC? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you generally pay tax on foreign investments in the country where you live, not the country where the investment is based. The companies in the S&P 500 pay US corporation tax on their profits, and that’s all that’s needed as far as the IRS is concerned, unless you are a US resident or US citizen.

Comment: So basically I can buy US stocks for free essentially? I thought there'd be some sort of favouritism towards US citizens?

Comment: @Primebrook You can’t buy them for free, you still have to pay for them. But you don’t have to pay income tax or capital gains tax on them if they’re in an ISA wrapper.

Comment: Haha, yes I didn't literally mean for free. Okay thank you very much. I must say I'm surprised - I can benefit from the high growth rates of the US economy as equally as a US citizen can. Is this available to any foreigner or is there some some agreement between the UK & US governments with regard to capital gains taxes etc?

Comment: The United States has treaties with many countries to avoid double taxation as well as for preventing tax evasion.  Here's a link to US-UK agreement .   I don't know the details.  Have fun reading it :->)
(https://www.irs.gov/businesses/international-businesses/united-kingdom-uk-tax-treaty-documents)

Comment: Enlightened countries actively encourage inward investment from foreigners.  When you invest in the US, that helps create American jobs, and people with jobs pay taxes.  But if a country put up too many barriers, the foreign investors will just deploy their funds elsewhere, or at home (old saying: money goes where it's wanted and stays where it's well treated).

Comment: I am not sure about the very first sentence of this answer. The dividends and capital gains paid by a US mutual fund to a foreign nonresident investor are surely taxable US income to the investor, and the US nonresident may need to file a US nonresident return (Form 1040NR). Most tax treaties are about avoidance of double taxation and say things like income that is taxed by the US is not taxed by the other government while the US will not tax the foreign income of the foreign nonresident of the US. In some cases, it is a credit: HMRC might credit taxes paid to the US against taxes due to HMRC

Comment: @Dilip: Agree "foreign investments" is a bit broad, but it's accurate in the context of the question which is about a UK investor investing in a UK fund which invests in the US.  Whatever international tax stuff there is happens within the fund (I've no idea what the details of that are, but things can obviously be done efficiently enough that the fund can track the index accurately without some big "tax drag").